# Cant navigate to button outside of scrollview with keyboard navigation

Tags: android

I have a layout that has a header, footer and a scrollview in between

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:text="@string/player_settings" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        .....

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/start"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:text="Start" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:text="Close"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/save"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Save" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The app is going to be used with a keyboard so I am using the arrow buttons to navigate and when I get the the bottom of the scrollview to the `close` button it should go to the save button but it just stays at the close button. As you can see I even set the `nextFocusDown` to be the save button but it still does not go.

Any ideas why it gets stuck on the button and never navigates to the save button outside the scrollview?

Comment: Are you trying on actual device? I tried your Xml and it works on my emulator

Comment: yes actual device, but maybe its the device then

Comment: Have you tried Ronny's answer yet ??

Answer (score 0):

I tried with emulator and laptop keyboard's down arrow. My emulator setting is set to use physical keyboard. it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add focus to the buttons with the android property: `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`
and according to the arrows pressed to navigate with the keyboard, you need to add the following properties with the id you want to go to:

⬅ android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/nameid"

⬆ android:nextFocusUp="@+id/nameid"

➡ android:nextFocusRight="@+id/nameid"

⬇ android:nextFocusDown="@+id/nameid"

[image]

This is your layout with my corrections:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/player_settings"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:singleLine="true"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:text="Start"
                android:nextFocusRight="@+id/close"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:text="Close"
                android:nextFocusRight="@+id/save"
                android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/start"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/close"
            android:text="Save" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```